# I need seven cascading dropdown levels with JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I expanded a code from W3Schools that had only three levels, but it's not working past the second level for me. I don't know how much exactly to share, so I'm sharing the entire html form. Hope this isn't too long.

The first half of it is me describing the dropdowns, the second half is what I believe to be the expansion of a code I found on W3Schools. But I fear I might not have gotten the expansion correctly. What did I miss/what other methods would you suggest.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
    var productCategory = {
      "Kitchen": {
        "Ingredients": {
          "Tomato paste": {
            "Gino": {
              "Tin": {
                "200g": ["Gino Tin Tomato 200g"],
                "300g": ["Gino Tin Tomato 300g"]
              },
              "Sachet": {
                "200g": ["Gino Sachet Tomato 200g"],
                "300g": ["Gino Sachet Tomato 300g"]
              }
            },
            "Double King": {
              "Tin": {
                "200g": ["Double King Tin Tomato 200g"],
                "300g": ["Double King Tin Tomato 300g"]
              },
              "Sachet": {
                "200g": ["Double King Sachet Tomato 200g"],
                "300g": ["Double King Sachet Tomato 300g"]
              }
            }
          },
          "Salt": {
            "Brand 1": {
              "Bag": {
                "400g": ["Brand 1 Salt 400g"],
                "500g": ["Brand 1 Salt 500g"]
              },
              "Bottle": {
                "350g": ["Brand 1 Salt Bottle 350g"],
                "600g": ["Brand 1 Salt Bottle 600g"],
                "900g": ["Brand 1 Salt Bottle 900g"]
              }
            },
            "Dangote": {
              "Bag": {
                "400g": ["Brand 1 Salt 400g"],
                "500g": ["Brand 1 Salt 500g"]
              },
              "Bottle": {
                "350g": ["Brand 1 Salt Bottle 350g"],
                "600g": ["Brand 1 Salt Bottle 600g"],
                "900g": ["Brand 1 Salt Bottle 900g"]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Utensils": {
          "Spoon": {
            "Phillips": {
              "Box": {
                "10 pieces": ["Phillips 10 spoons"],
                "20 pieces": ["Phillips 20 spoons"]
              }
            },
            "Binatone": {
              "Box": {
                "10 pieces": ["Binatone 10 spoons"],
                "20 pieces": ["Binatone 20 spoons"]
              }
            }

          },
          "Fork": {
            "Phillips": {
              "Box": {
                "10 pieces": ["Phillips 10 forks"],
                "20 pieces": ["Phillips 20 forks"]
              }
            },
            "Binatone": {
              "Box": {
                "10 pieces": ["Binatone 10 forks"],
                "20 pieces": ["Binatone 20 forks"]
              }
            }
          },
          "Knife": {
            "Phillips": {
              "Box": {
                "10 pieces": ["Phillips 10 knives"],
                "20 pieces": ["Phillips 20 knives"]
              }
            },
            "Binatone": {
              "Box": {
                "10 pieces": ["Binatone 10 knives"],
                "20 pieces": ["Binatone 20 knives"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Electrical": {
        "Accessories": {
          "Switch": {
            "Binatone": {
              "Single": {
                "2-pin": ["Binatone 2-pin switch"],
                "3-pin": ["Binatone 3-pin switch"]
              },
              "Pack": {
                "2-pin": ["Binatone pack of 2-pin switches"],
                "3-pin": ["Binatone pack of 3-pin switches"]
              }
            },
            "Phillips": {
              "Single": {
                "2-pin": ["Phillips 2-pin switch"],
                "3-pin": ["Phillips 3-pin switch"]
              },
              "Pack": {
                "2-pin": ["Phillips pack of 2-pin switches"],
                "3-pin": ["Phillips pack of 3-pin switches"]
              }
            }
          },
          "Lampholder": {
            "Binatone": {
              "Single": {
                "Large": ["Binatone large Lampholder"],
                "Small": ["Binatone small Lampholder"]
              },
              "Pack": {
                "Large": ["Binatone pack of Lampholders"],
                "Small": ["Binatone pack of Lampholders"]
              }
            },
            "Phillips": {
              "Single": {
                "Large": ["Binatone large Lampholder"],
                "Small": ["Binatone small Lampholder"]
              },
              "Pack": {
                "Large": ["Binatone pack of Lampholders"],
                "Small": ["Binatone pack of Lampholders"]
              }
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }


    window.onload = function() {
      var sectionSel = document.getElementById("section");
      var subsectionSel = document.getElementById("subsection");
      var subsubsectionSel = document.getElementById("subsubsection");
      var brandSel = document.getElementById("brand");
      var itemtypeSel = document.getElementById("itemtype");
      var itemsizeSel = document.getElementById("itemsize");
      var itemnameSel = document.getElementById("itemname");
      for (var t in productCategory) {
        sectionSel.options[sectionSel.options.length] = new Option(t, t);
      }
      sectionSel.onchange = function() {        //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
               
        itemnameSel.length = 1;       
        itemsizeSel.length = 1;       
        itemtypeSel.length = 1;       
        brandSel.length = 1;       
        subsubsectionSel.length = 1;       
        subsectionSel.length = 1;
        //display correct values
        for (var u in productCategory[this.value]) {
          subsectionSel.options[subsectionSel.options.length] = new Option(u, u);
        }
      }


      subsectionSel.onchange = function() {        //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
               
        itemnameSel.length = 1;       
        itemsizeSel.length = 1;       
        itemtypeSel.length = 1;       
        brandSel.length = 1;       
        subsubsectionSel.length = 1;
        //display correct values
        for (var v in productCategory[this.value]) {
          subsubsectionSel.options[subsubsectionSel.options.length] = new Option(v, v);
        }
      }


      subsubsectionSel.onchange = function() {        //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
               
        itemnameSel.length = 1;       
        itemsizeSel.length = 1;       
        itemtypeSel.length = 1;       
        brandSel.length = 1;

        //display correct values
        for (var w in productCategory[this.value]) {
          brandSel.options[brandSel.options.length] = new Option(w, w);
        }
      }


      brandSel.onchange = function() {        //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
               
        itemnameSel.length = 1;       
        itemsizeSel.length = 1;       
        itemtypeSel.length = 1;

        //display correct values
        for (var x in productCategory[this.value]) {
          itemtypeSel.options[itemtypeSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
        }
      }


      itemtypeSel.onchange = function() {        //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
               
        itemnameSel.length = 1;       
        itemsizeSel.length = 1;

        //display correct values
        for (var y in productCategory[this.value]) {
          itemsizeSel.options[itemsizeSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
        }
      }

      itemsizeSel.onchange = function() {        //empty Chapters dropdown
               
        itemnameSel.length = 1;
        //display correct values
        var z = productCategory[sectionSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
          itemnameSel.options[itemnameSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
        }
      }

      /*
        brandSel.onchange = function() {
          //empty Chapters dropdown
          itemtypeSel.length = 1;
          //display correct values
          var z = productCategory[sectionSel.value][this.value];
          for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            itemtypeSel.options[itemtypeSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
          }
        } 
    
        */
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Cascading Dropdown Example</h1>

  <form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
    Category:
    <select name="section" id="section">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Section</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Sub-category:
    <select name="subsection" id="subsection">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select sub-category</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Sub-sub-category:
    <select name="subsubsection" id="subsubsection">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select sub-sub-category</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Brand:
    <select name="brand" id="brand">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select brand</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Packaging:
    <select name="itemtype" id="itemtype">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select package type</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Size:
    <select name="itemsize" id="itemsize">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select size</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Product name:
    <select name="itemname" id="itemname">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select item name</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please turn this into a StackSnippet so that it's easy for others to reproduce

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it eventually. There was a slight bug in the dictionary. Then, I also needed to expand the for loops.

For example:

```js
for (var w in productCategory[catDropdown.value][subCatDropdown.value][this.value]) {
    brandDropdown.options[brandDropdown.options.length] = new Option(w, w);
}
```